# T-SQL update 1 to 1000 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a column in a table 1 to 10000

which is the best method for doing this.

Environment: Sql Server 2008.

I thought a may be

```
USE []
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [userid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into mytable(userid,name)Values (1,'a')
insert into mytable(userid,name)Values (6,'b')
insert into mytable(userid,name)Values (7,'c')
insert into mytable(userid,name)Values (8,'d')
insert into mytable(userid,name)Values (9,'e')
GO
```

then an error msg56, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

```
USE MD
SELECT userid = 0, * FROM mytable INTO #tmp_data

DECLARE @userid int
SET @userid = 0
UPDATE #tmp_data
SET @userid= userid = @userid + 1
```

where have I gone wrong

Comment: Please post what do you want your table to look like after all these operations.

Comment: ??? what are you trying to do??? And where exactly is something failing?? The CREATE TABLE and the INSERT INTO statements work just fine - so what's the issue, really?? You're not being very clear....

Comment: -1: Very difficult to determine what is being asked here.

Comment: I *think* he wants a table with 1000 rows, with values 1-1000. Or is it 10000 rows, 1-10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is

```
SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...
```

The UPDATE statement does not look correct, either. But I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is required. But this will give you a temp table with incremented userid:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp_data  FROM mytable 

UPDATE #tmp_data 
SET userid = userid + 1
```

Comment: this work thanks   SELECT userid = 0, * INTO #tmp_data FROM mytable go DECLARE @userid int SET @userid = 0 UPDATE mytable SET @userid=userid = @userid + 1 USE MD select * from mytable.